# Configure site on multiple ports

Tags: apache, apache2, debian

I want configure multiple sites on difference ports. My IP is 192.168.50.4 and on port 80 is standard apache2 site "It works". I want bind secound site to port *:8080. This port is binded to "It works" site instead my custom site.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.50.4:8080
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>

      # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
      ServerAdmin webmaster@test.t
      ServerName  site1
      #ServerAlias www.localhost


      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are loca$
      DirectoryIndex index.html, index.php
      DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/www/vhosts/test.t/htdocs

        <Directory /home/vagrant/www/vhosts/test.t/htdocs/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                allow from all
        </Directory>

      # Custom log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  /home/vagrant/www/vhosts/test.t/log/error.log
      CustomLog /home/vagrant/www/vhosts/test.t/log/access.log combin$

    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (most of the configuration omitted for clarity):

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.50.4:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/www/vhosts/test.t/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you've actually enabled the site and reloaded Apache:

```
a2ensite test
service apache2 reload
```

And also make sure you're accessing it under the right IP address (e.g. not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`).